# Fastest editor/ide for for TDD workflow: test > code > test?

Tags: ide, tdd, editor, workflow

I've found that test first development can be painful if the workflow is slow.  It can take a long time to write a test, compile, run the tests, write code, compile, then run the tests again.  Part of the problem is that the delays to compile and run tests to some extent interrupts my flow.  When my brain has an idea, I want to be able to get it out and test it quickly.

I'm looking for an editor or IDE that does TDD well.  By well, I mean:

- TDD workflow can be done entirely using keyboard shortcuts
- Tests are launched quickly
- Easy to view test results
- Fast compilation (I know this depends on language/code size)
- Overall speed

The 2 languages I care about are C# and Python.

What editor/IDE do you use?  What does your workflow look like (i.e. the things you need to click on, the keyboard shortcuts you use, etc.) to complete one new method using TDD? any recommendations?

Comment: with C#, I'm not sure you can do any better than the latest version of VS. Use Resharper / CodeRush if you want IDE integration. If you value the end-goal more than the means + your tests are in NUNit: you can open the NUnit GUI + configure it such that it re-runs the tests every time you rebuild. 2 monitors/side-by-side windows and you're golden. Also check out my VS extension - Beacons ; "might" be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Eclipse & JUnit.  Run Last Launched is Ctrl-F11, and I've configured it so that running my tests automatically saves my changes (Preferences --> Run/Debug --> Launching --> Save Required Dirty Editors Before Launching).  Last week a friend gave me a small test; we found that in 12 minutes of coding at top speed, I had run my tests 36 times.  Every 20 seconds my tests run, including save, compile, run, and watch the red/green.  This wasn't a test to see how fast I could run my tests; it was an incidental and, at least to us, interesting data point.  When I'm at my best, I'm running my tests three times a minute; Eclipse and JUnit make that possible.

I've used Visual Studio with its native test system (nunit?  I've forgotten); switching between the "I"DE and the test runner is infuriating.  I know there are plugins available that eliminate that pain, and I'd recommend finding them.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I work on the CodeRush design and development team.

Right now CodeRush for Visual Studio appears to be the fastest test runner available for .NET, and the CodeRush TDD experience is entirely keyboard driven and designed to be optimally efficient.

Some news about the CodeRush 10.2 test runner:

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2010/12/15/visual-studio-s-greatest-test-runner-take-a-look-at-coderush-10-2.aspx

See the **Declare** section on this page for a sense of the TDD experience (we call these features consume-first declarations):

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx

And here are some independent test run time results comparing CodeRush with a number of competitors (be sure to read the text and not just the table -- the reported times for one of those test runners was apparently 20 seconds shorter than the actual time spent waiting to see the results):

http://www.mikehanson.com/post/MSTest-vs-NUnit-Run-Times.aspx#disqus_thread

Answer (score 3):

vim/bash/screen

The workflow is this: (starting from command mode in a vim session editing the source files)

to compile and run the test suite: <right-arrow><up-arrow><enter>
(left and right arrow keys are bound to prev and next in screen, the next window is a bash terminal and the up-arrow selects the previous command which is 'make check', but can be modified to work with any language: the previous command should simply be the command to run your test suite)

If the unit test of function "foo" fails:
<left-arrow>:ta foo<edit>

I still do not understand why IDE's are so praised.  Modularity is good.  Integration is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found Visual Studio + [Test Driven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/) to be the best. The test runner built into VS2008 is, I agree, fairly slow.

Netbeans is pretty fast too, but that's not for C#...

Answer (score 0):

I use NUnit - by default NUnit automatically reloads your assembly when recompiled, and you can also set NUnit to re-run the tests on reload.

I simply have the IDE (VS.Net) and NUnit side-by-side (dual monitor in my case).  As soon as I compile (shft-ctrl-b) I get build and test happening without any other intervention.

I also set my UnitTests project to be my startup project, ctrl-f5 runs NUnit loaded with my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Open a separate terminal window, and run sniffer or autonose. Give it the left side of your screen. Open your editor in the upper right side of the screen.

Sniffer/autonose are basically python versions of ruby's autotest. Every time you save a file in the python project, it runs your test suite. Continual testing tools like these are a better world than tying the test run to a keystroke. Once you've spent a day with them, you won't miss visual studio.

For editors, use anything you like -- testing doesn't depend on your editor. Use vim, emacs, pyscripter, wing, pydev -- have a good time. use them all at once.

For C# work I always use resharper, and get used to running the tests with mouse or keystroke. It's not quite as nice, but nothings as nice as python + continual